# What is the order of precedence for collect(nodes(path)) in cypher

Tags: neo4j

Sorry for the noob question.
If I do collect(nodes(A - member -> B - member -> C )), is there a way to guarantee that a property in A overrides the same property in C?

I am thinking of this in terms of class hierarchy in OO.

thanks in advance,
jerry

Comment: Do you mean to get a merging of the property maps, with properties of nodes earlier in the path overriding the properties of the same name from later in the path?

Comment: So for a matched path, `nodes(path)` is the collection of nodes in that path.

`collect(nodes(path))` with collect across all paths the collections of nodes in the paths. Basically a list of a list of nodes. Is that what you want? There's no overriding happening here.

Comment: Can you an example to better illustrate your need? Also do you know the property that should be present in both the first and last node of the collection, and is it only a single property that has to be the same? Do you need that to hold true for all of the collected node lists?

Comment: @Jerrys What exactly do you mean by "A - member -> B - member -> C"? It is not an expression in legal Cypher syntax. Is it supposed to be a sample path, or something else?